How to properly convert a token to cast it in UserPrincipal?
I'm lost.
I'm trying to manage a fake backend for my training, in Java+SpringBoot+Maven.
What I normally do, when a user logs in is to create a Jwt and then send it to the Front end.
public Map<String, Object> loginUser(LoginRequest loginRequest, BindingResult result) {
        //managing errors here
            try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginRequest.getUsername(), 
                loginRequest.getPassword())
            );
            User user = repository.findByUsername(loginRequest.getUsername())
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    
            String jwtToken = JwtService.createJwtToken(user);
    
            var response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            response.put("user", user);
            response.put("token", jwtToken);
            return response;
            }
            
            //managing errors 

            return null;
    }

This is the way I create and encode a JWT:
@Service
public class JwtService {

    //values here

    public String createJwtToken(User user) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
            .subject(user.getUsername())
            .issuer(jwtIssuer)
            .issuedAt(now)
            .expiresAt(now.plusSeconds(jwtLength))
            .claim("isAdmin", user.getIsAdmin())
            .build();

        var encoder = new NimbusJwtEncoder(
            new ImmutableSecret<>(jwtSecretKey.getBytes()));
        var params = JwtEncoderParameters.from(
            JwsHeader.with(MacAlgorithm.HS256).build(), claims);
        return encoder.encode(params).getTokenValue();
    }
}

And, finally, in the SecurityConfig I have, among other things:
@Bean SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth 
            .requestMatchers("/users/register", "/users/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(
                SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .build();
    }

@Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        var secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(jwtSecretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKey)
            .macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256)
            .build();
    }

  
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserService userService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();   
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(provider);
    }

Now, the thing is that I'm not able to make it work the other way round, when I receive this token from the frontend for his HTTP requests.
Especially here (that is the first route I was trying to implement):
@PostMapping("/send")
public ResponseEntity<?> sendMessage(@Valid @RequestBody NewMessage newMessage, BindingResult result, Authentication auth) {

//managing errors here

    try {
        Long senderId = ((UserPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal()).getId();
        chatService.sendMessage(senderId, newMessage);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
// managing errors here
    }

But it works here (even if here I'm not using the UserPrincipal, indeed, but it still with the Jwt (no!?):
@GetMapping("/profile")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> personalProfile(Authentication auth) {
    var response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("Username", auth.getName());
    response.put("Authorities", auth.getAuthorities());

    var user = repository.findByUsername(auth.getName());
    response.put("User", user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
  }

I have tried several things but, when I try to send a message, in Maven's logs I can read that the problem is to cast the Token in the UserPrincipal.
What I suppose could be the problems (but I'm not sure how to solve them):

the token has WAY MORE parameters than the UserPrincipal. Becase my User entity has 15 columns/parameters/things and my UserPrincipal has only 3 (I was just trying to use in its most simple form - username, mail, password - and then maybe implement all the things), so, maybe, this can be a first problem.

I define a JwtDecoder both in securityConfig AND in JwtService. Here, I must admit I have taken things here and there from internet (I must say SpringBoot documentation is not clear and doesn't help, in my case) and maybe I made a mess.

I should also create a Jwt Converter, but I'm completely lost.


